# Delete remote files matching local files, or delete files as they are downloaded

Tags: linux, files, zsh, rsync

Say we have two hosts `producer` and `consumer` and the following process:

1. `producer` adds files **regularly** to `/some/path`.
2. `consumer` pulls those files to **its own** `/some/path` (e.g. via `rsync`) and **processes** them.
3. We now need `consumer` to  **delete** the processed files (and only the processed files) in **both hosts.**

Can (3) be accomplished with `rsync` or an equivalent command by  `consumer` ?

---

Alternatively, can we have `consumer` easily delete the files from `producer` that it downloads as it processes step (2)?

---

Note that `producer` is always creating files, and we want to make sure we process each file in `consumer` once and only once.

Comment: I don't know if you control the consumer "process" but it sounds like the program that "processes" the files should be removing the local and remote files once it is completed.

Comment: Sounds likeva job for rsync...

Comment: Thanks @ZacharyBrady yes, that's exactly what I am hoping to do with `consumer`. Once it's done processing the files, we want it to delete them from both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `consumer` you can use this rsync command.

```
rsync -az --remove-source-files user@producer:/some/path/ /some/path/
```

Then when the process is complete have your `consumer` process delete the file.

```
rm -f /some/path/file
```